# Subtraction overflow encountered while attempting to flip image byte array

Tags: arrays, image

I have a basic image class which supports loading a `png` into a byte array:

```rust
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
use png;
use png::ColorType::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct PixelArray {
    pub width: usize,
    pub height: usize,
    pub channels: usize,
    pub data: Vec<u8>
}

impl PixelArray {
    pub fn load_png<T: AsRef<Path>>(path: T) -> std::io::Result<PixelArray> {
        let mut decoder = png::Decoder::new(File::open(path)?);
        decoder.set_transformations(png::Transformations::normalize_to_color8());
        let mut reader = decoder.read_info()?;
        let mut img_data = vec![0; reader.output_buffer_size()];
        let info = reader.next_frame(&mut img_data)?;

        let (data, channels) = match info.color_type {
            Rgb => (img_data, 3),
            Rgba => (img_data, 4),
            Grayscale => (
                {
                    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(img_data.len() * 3);
                    for g in &img_data {
                        vec.extend([g, g, g].iter().cloned())
                    }
                    vec
                }, 3),
            GrayscaleAlpha => (
                {
                    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(img_data.len() * 3);
                    for ga in img_data.chunks(2) {
                        let g = ga[0];
                        let a = ga[1];
                        vec.extend([g, g, g, a].iter().cloned())
                    }
                    vec
                }, 4),
            _ => unreachable!("uncovered color type"),
        };

        Ok(PixelArray {
            width: info.width as usize,
            height: info.height as usize,
            channels,
            data: data
        })
    }

    pub fn data(&self) -> &Vec<u8> {
        &self.data
    }

    pub fn flipv(&mut self) {
        for x in 0..(self.width * 4) {
            for y in 0..(self.height * 4) {
                self.data[x * self.width + y] = self.data[x * self.width + (self.width - 1 - y)];
            }
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
  let mut img = PixelArray::load_png("text.png").unwrap();
  img.flipv();
}
```

The issue is not with loading a png, but with vertically flipping the png. My existing solution produces the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src/main.rs:61:76
```

How can this issue be rectified?

Note: the image mentioned in the source code can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vykp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a different algorithm for flipping the image. Here is the result:

```rust
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use png;
use png::ColorType::*;
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct PixelArray {
    pub width: usize,
    pub height: usize,
    pub data: Vec<RGBA>
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Copy)]
pub struct RGBA {
    pub r: u8,
    pub g: u8,
    pub b: u8,
    pub a: u8
}

impl PixelArray {
    pub fn load_png<T: AsRef<Path>>(path: T) -> std::io::Result<PixelArray> {
        let mut decoder = png::Decoder::new(File::open(path)?);
        decoder.set_transformations(png::Transformations::normalize_to_color8());
        let mut reader = decoder.read_info()?;
        let mut img_data = vec![0; reader.output_buffer_size()];
        let info = reader.next_frame(&mut img_data)?;
    
        // Convert RGB and Grayscale to RGBA by adding 1 for alpha channel
        let data = match info.color_type {
            Rgb => {
                let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(img_data.len() * 3);
                for rgb in img_data.chunks(3) {
                    let r = rgb[0];
                    let g = rgb[1];
                    let b = rgb[2];
                    vec.extend([r, g, b, 1].iter().cloned())
                }
                vec
            }
            Rgba => img_data,
            Grayscale =>
                {
                    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(img_data.len() * 3);
                    for g in &img_data {
                        vec.extend([g, g, g, &1].iter().cloned())
                    }
                    vec
                },
            GrayscaleAlpha =>
                {
                    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(img_data.len() * 3);
                    for ga in img_data.chunks(2) {
                        let g = ga[0];
                        let a = ga[1];
                        vec.extend([g, g, g, a].iter().cloned())
                    }
                    vec
                },
            _ => unreachable!("uncovered color type"),
        };
        
        let mut pixels = Vec::new();
        for i in (0..data.len()).step_by(4) {
            let pixel = RGBA { r: data[i], g: data[i + 1], b: data[i + 2], a: data[i + 3] };
            pixels.push(pixel);
        }
        Ok(PixelArray {
            width: info.width as usize,
            height: info.height as usize,
            data: pixels
        })
    }
    
    pub fn data(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut flattened_data = Vec::new();
        for i in 0..self.width {
            for j in 0..self.height {
                let pixel = self[[i, j]];
                let r = pixel.r;
                let g = pixel.g;
                let b = pixel.b;
                let a = pixel.a;
                flattened_data.push(r);
                flattened_data.push(g);
                flattened_data.push(b);
                flattened_data.push(a);
            }
        }
        flattened_data
    }
    
    pub fn flipv(&mut self) {
        let mut new_data = self.clone();
        for i in 0..self.height {
            for j in 0..self.width {
                new_data[[i, j]] = self[[(self.height - 1 - i), j]];
            }
        }
        self.data = new_data.data;
    }
}

impl Index<[usize; 2]> for PixelArray {
    type Output = RGBA;
    
    fn index(&self, index: [usize; 2]) -> &Self::Output {
        let [i, j] = index;
        if i >= self.height || j >= self.width {
            panic!("Image index out of bounds");
        }
        
        &self.data[(self.width * i) + j]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<[usize; 2]> for PixelArray {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: [usize; 2]) -> &mut Self::Output {
        let [i, j] = index;
        if i >= self.height || j >= self.width {
            panic!("Image index out of bounds");
        }
        
        &mut self.data[(self.width * i) + j]
    }
}
```